# Bind9 and different zone locations

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, apparmor

I'm just trying to get a DNS server off the ground and most of the guides I followed online tells me to create zone files in **/etc/bind/zones** or **just /etc/bind/**.  But I want to use a different path, **/server/zones**. I changed the permissions and owners of the folders with:

***chmod -R 640 /servers*** and ***chown -R root:bind /servers*** as well as adding the line "/servers/** rw," to ***/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.named***

When I check my logs I get a permission denied message for the directory /servers/zones...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chmod -R 640 /servers` will remove the execute bit from the /servers directory. Non-root users need execute permissions on directories in order access their contents.

Instead, try using the X symbolic mode which will set the recursively set executable bit on directories, but not files:

```
chmod -R u=rwX,g=rX,o= /servers
```

From the chmod man page:

> The letters `rwxXst` select file mode bits for the affected users:
>   read (`r`), write (`w`), execute (or search for directories) (`x`),
>   **execute/search only if the file is a directory or already has execute
>   permission for some user (`X`)**,

Comment: Can you point to the supporting info for where that command would only affect directories and not files? I always used a find to do this sort of operation but am always in search of a "new" trick =)

Comment: Added a reference to the chmod man page. The `X` can affect files, but only if they're are already execute privileges on another user.

Comment: ahh, thank you...always good to learn another new tip =)

Comment: I see, I didn't Bind would need exec access, just read & write.